# I have a 16 Port Gigabit router connected to an unmanaged switch

Tags: networking, router

I have a 16 Port Gigabit router connected to an unmanaged switch. Can I hang three servers with Gigabit network cards off the router (For the GB speed to the cloud) and still see the servers from the other users connected to the unmanaged switch? I will use Cat 6 cable between the servers and the router. The servers will have static 192... addresses that are within the scope of the DHCP the router will feed to the unmanaged switch users. Thanks in advance!

Joel

Comment: What's the model of the router?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You use a router when you want to have separate Ethernet LANs, each with its own separate IPv4 subnet, with no typical LAN multicast service discovery between LANs. You will still have IP connectivity between LANs, and you will still be able to connect between LANs via IP address or hostname, but you won't be able to "see" those servers on other LANs/subnets when you try to "browse" for them.

There are ways to make some service discovery protocols work across subnets, but that topic gets complicated quickly.